# Capturar dados de email

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Boa noite.

Preciso de uma ajuda, vou tentar ser o mais claro possível.

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação de chamados, quero deixar o pessoal abrir chamados por e-mail, como eu posso capturar esses dados do corpo do e-mail?

Por exemplo: Eu envio um e-mail com os dados do chamado(titulo, descricao, empresa, etc..) quero que minha aplicação capture esses dados e insira no BD.

É possível?

Obs.: Quero deixar claro que não quero códigos prontos, quero apenas ideias.

Obrigado.

Comment: caso tenha acesso administrativo ao servidor, pode criar scripts de escuta com o procmail, em ambientes linux. Pesquise no google "php procmail piping"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na minha opinião o método mais simples seria criar uma conta de e-mail específica e consultá-la de tempos em tempos usando PHP IMAP para ler os e-mails, armazenar no banco e apagar.

O problema mesmo é o "parse" do texto, vai ser preciso combinar um formato com os usuários ou enviar um e-mail de confirmação com os dados já formatados para que o usuário confirme.

Dê uma olhada na API: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php

Comment: Sim, será criada uma conta de e-mail específica para este fim